# Issue with awaiting promises in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, async-await

I have implemented retry logic for one API call like below:

```
private async fetchRecordingStatus(user: User): Promise<RecordingStatus[]> {
        const rs: RecordingStatus[] = [];
        let noOfRetries = 10;
        while (noOfRetries >= 0) {
            try {
                const userLineRecordingStatus = await this.getUserRecordingStatus(user.userid);
                 this.logger.log(`Preparing recording config status of userid:  ${hrUser.userid}`);

              // some processing  
                break;
            } catch (err) {
                if (noOfRetries === 0) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    this.logger.log(`Retry preparing recording config status of user: ${user.userid}`);
                    noOfRetries -= 1;
                    // wait for 2 seconds before trying
                    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
                }
            }
        }
        return rs;
 }
```

In the above code I'm calling the **fetchRecordingStatus** method from client code(for around 10,000 users in a loop). However for some reason when the API call(getUserRecordingStatus) fails flow seems to hang instead of retrying the logic. In the logs I could see the retry statement printed once but that's it. Any ideas if I'm missing something? Thanks for your help.

DEMO:

```js
async function fetchRecordingStatus(user) {
  const rs = [];
  let noOfRetries = 5;
  while (noOfRetries >= 0) {
    try {
      const userLineRecordingStatus = await Promise.reject(new Error('fail'));
      console.log(`Preparing recording config status of userid:`);

      // some processing  
      break;
    } catch (err) {
      if (noOfRetries === 0) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        console.log(`Retry preparing recording config status of user: `);
        noOfRetries -= 1;
        // wait for 2 seconds before trying
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
      }
    }
  }
  return rs;
}
fetchRecordingStatus()
```

Comment: I have added a demo in your post. Your retry logic seems to work fine.

Comment: Show code for getUserRecordingStatus please

Comment: @palaѕн I also tried throwing like you did and it worked fine in my local machine but in real deployment with actual API calls it is failing :(

Comment: @AlexBrohshtut There is a lot of logic in that actually but under the hood it just make an API call to some system and returns the result. But it definitely either returns or fails. That is for sure.

Comment: At least we now know that this part of your code is working fine. The main issue is with `this.getUserRecordingStatus` api call. It might be doing some more inner api calls and there might be loops with async/await and the result is not properly returned.

Comment: @palaѕн Just to test that  I moved that log statement before making an API call but it didn't get printed.

Comment: Exactly, as @palaѕн said, the issue is probably that you never reject / throw in this called function. Anyway, you can debug it and see the stack trace to understand where this is stuck.